# A formula for speed in a game about hiking. The variables include weather, weight of equipment, quality-score of equipment, etc

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic-game-theory

excited to post here for the first time...

I am creating a game about hiking a (never ending) mountain. The game isn't a "runner." Instead it is strategic, where the player chooses their inventory every in-game day. The issue I am having is constructing a formula to calculate the player's speed.

Some variables that will have great effect on the speed include: random weather, oxygen intake, altitude (which exponentially slows the speed), equipment quality (the better the quality, the heavier the equipment), equipment weight, and food/food weight.

I'm open to any and all suggestions, including to tools I can use help constructing this crazy equation.

Thanks!

Comment: When problems are reduced to a mathematical model, then we can help.  In the process of reducing your situation to a mathematical model, your preferences and ambitions play a larger role than mathematical reasoning can.  You might look at the conditioning of the in-game character as another variable (their strength vs. resting statistics, etc.).  At the high-end you might look at records for hiking such as the Appalachian Trial for paces that can be sustained for a long period of time.

Comment: A simple model is to use a bunch of multiplicative factors, e.g.: speed = (normal speed) * (health adjustment) * (weather adjustment) * (oxygen adjustment) * (altitude adjustment) * (equipment adjustment) * (weight adjustment) * (hunger adjustment).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want some “real-life” numbers.

> altitude

You could use [Naismith's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naismith%27s_rule): Every 2000 feet (609.6 m) of ascent adds one hour to a hike.

> equipment weight, and food/food weight.

[A study](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-effect-of-increasing-backpack-load-on-the-walking-speed-and-double-support-time_fig1_316877875) involving teenage girls found that a backpack load of 15% of body weight results in a 10% slowdown of walking speed.

Extrapolating this to a simple linear model, that works out to:

$$s(w) = (1 - \frac{2}{3}w)s(0)$$

Where $s(w)$ is the character's walking speed while carrying a weight of $w$ (expressed as a proportion of the character's body weight).  And $s(0)$ = normal walking speed when not carrying any weight, probably around 3 miles or 5 km per hour.